# Google I/O 2011 Development Tools Video - Where did the create new button go?

Tags: android

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oq05KqjXTvs if you scroll to 16:10 roughly, he creates a new layout. I don't see that button. I know it's been two years since the video, but I'm trying to replicate what he is doing and I can't find it in eclipse now.

Comment: My guess is that it was considered redundant and removed. You can still specify certain quantifiers when creating a new XML Layout file and it'll throw it into the correct folder for you.

Answer (score 1):

First you must left click on the res/layout folder , then click on the button to add xml layout files (marked in red). Then just follow the dialog and picture.
[image]
[image]